# How to setup local Environment for Ember JS

Tags: ember.js

i'am new to ember Js.when i setup local environment for Ember Js getting some error and i have installed following software 1) Node Js 2)git 3)ebmer-cli 4)bower 5)bootstarp and what else i need to install.when try to hit index.html(from app folder) in browser i'm getting following Exception in browser console & browser.kindly refer image[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to format your question better?  Also, this is not the correct way to run an ember-cli application.  Have you followed these steps? http://www.ember-cli.com/#getting-started

Comment: i did same way..but not working for me

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you are trying to open your application directly from the filesystem.

You need to run `ember server` command in your project directory and navigate to `http://localhost:4200`